# How to change number of items on add new pluggins page from backend?

Tags: categories, user-interface

When adding new plugins, the list is too short, and I have to click on next, next , next...

Is there a way to change the number of items to be displayed to something like 100 or 500?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the parameters for this view per `install_plugins_table_api_args_search`. See `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php` for the details.

You get an array as argument that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 1
    [per_page] => 30
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [last_updated] => 1
            [icons] => 1
            [active_installs] => 1
        )

    [locale] => en_US
    [installed_plugins] => Array
        (
            [0] => magic-widgets
            [1] => query-monitor
        )

    [search] => seo
)
```

So you can just set the `per_page` entry to a higher value. This will also slow down the response, because more data is transferred from wordpress.org.

Here is a sample plugin:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: 200 plugins per install search
 */

add_filter( 'install_plugins_table_api_args_search', function ( array $args ) {

    $args['per_page'] = 200;
    return $args;
});
```